# Print file count owned by a given user

Tags: shell, awk, find, csh

How to print the number of files owned by every user in a given directory?
So far I am printing user name and disk size. However I want to report out the output of "`find $dirname -user <user_name>| wc -l`" and print that as a third field in the below printf

```
set dirname = "a/b/c"

    find $dirname -printf "%u %s\n"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a feeling you want to do something like this :

```
find $dirname -printf "%u %s\n" \
 | awk '{s[$1]+=$2;c[$1]++}END{for(u in s) print u,s[u],c[u]}
```

This will print a list of users with total accumulated file-size and the total amount of files.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to get at! Did a lot of circus and foreach loops with find <dir_name> -user <user_name | wc -l followed by saving the contents into an array. Even then was lost on how to type the array as a 3rd column! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stat` `id` and `awk` to do something along these lines:

```
$ cd /var
$ stat -f '%u%t%N' * | awk -F$"\t" '{fn[$1][$2]} 
                                    END{for (u in fn){ 
                                        system("id -nu " u)
                                        for (e in fn[u]) print "\t" e
                         }}'
```

Prints

```
_jabber
    jabberd
root
    log
    rpc
    netboot
    lib
    db
    agentx
    run
    mail
    folders
    vm
    backups
    spool
    tmp
    install
    audit
    root
    empty
    yp
    msgs
_mobileasset
    ma
daemon
    rwho
    at
_networkd
    networkd
```

As written, it does not support file names with `\t` in them. Not a terribly hard fix (just concatenate the fields greater than $2 joined by `\t`), but you get the idea.

Comment: Should this not be `stat -c` (`man stat` states: _ The valid format sequences for files (without --file-system):_, i.e. the format specifiers don't work with `-f`)

Comment: Since `stat` is not POSIX, it may vary by system. On BSD / OS X, there is no `-c` command line switch for `stat`. Nor is there a `-printf` option to `find` so this is an area varies. On Linux, `find` with printf properly formatted is likely the best bet or `stat` with the translated switches.

Comment: Thanks that's an interesting way to do it! I was able to get it work